# Admob ads not working

Tags: android, admob

I have an admob account, in which 2 applications are connected and ads are working accurately , but when I try to add unit id in my third application, ads are not showing in that application

but other both application are working accurately , ads are coming in these,
help me why ads are not showing in my new application?

Comment: Set Test Admob Id for checking.

Comment: test id is working... but live ads are not coming

Comment: If it is recently created I think it takes a while until that unit shows. Make sure the ad id is copied accurately and doesn't contain spaces

Comment: id is copied accuratley

Comment: Check output in LogCat to see some possible error associated with ads.

Comment: okkkzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: everything is ok but still ads are not coming in that particular application

Comment: @PranavArora may be vavilable space is not huge enough

Comment: still my new ad id  not become active and other ad id are working good